# C++ pointers and table

Tags: c++, pointers, 2d

i'm learning C++ and i wanted to write a program that allocates 2D table using pointers. Here's my code:

```
bool b_alloc_table_2_dim(int ***piTable, int iSizeX, int iSizeY)
{
    if ((iSizeX && iSizeY) > 0)
    {
        *piTable = new int* [iSizeX];

        for (int i = 0; i < iSizeX; i++)
            (*piTable)[i] = new int[iSizeY];

        return true;
    }
    else return false;
}
bool b_dealloc_table_2_dim(int **piTable, int iSizeX)
{
    if (iSizeX > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < iSizeX; i++)
            delete[] piTable[i];
        delete[] piTable;

        return true;
    }
    else return false; 
}
```

After allocating a table, i want to deallocate it. I got this problem "HEAP[TEP_Lab1.exe]: Invalid address specified to RtlValidateHeap( 00DB0000, 00DB5B68 )". I don't know how to fix this.
Please, help!

```
int main()
{   
    int** piTable;
    
    b_alloc_table_2_dim(&piTable, 5, 3);
 
    b_dealloc_table_2_dim(piTable, 5);
}
```

Comment: How's the function `b_alloc_table_2_dim` being called? Can you add the code where the functions to allocated and de-allocate are being called?

Comment: Looks more like C than C++. But anyway, the code seems fine, can you make a [mre] please?

Comment: Unable to reproduce with the provided code. Check [here](https://onlinegdb.com/r18aiMywD)

Comment: As quickly as you can turn your learning toward std library containers like std::array and std::vector as a more acceptable way of doing arrays.  In general, code with new and delete is somewhat frowned upon as potentially leak-prone.  (There are usually better constructs available that will do the same thing.)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

this example is good for you:

```
int **dynamicArray = 0;
dynamicArray = new int *[ROWS];

// memory allocated for  elements of each column.  
for( int i = 0 ; i < ROWS ; i++ ) {
    dynamicArray[i] = new int[COLUMNS];
}

// free the allocated memory 
for( int i = 0 ; i < ROWS ; i++ ) {
    delete [] dynamicArray[i];
}
delete [] dynamicArray;
```

now your corrected code is

```
bool b_alloc_table_2_dim(int **piTable, int iSizeX, int iSizeY)
{
    if ((iSizeX && iSizeY) > 0)
    {
        piTable = new int* [iSizeX];

        for (int i = 0; i < iSizeX; i++)
            piTable[i] = new int[iSizeY];

        return true;
    }
    else return false;
}
bool b_dealloc_table_2_dim(int **piTable, int iSizeX)
{
    if (iSizeX > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < iSizeX; i++)
            delete[] piTable[i];
        delete[] piTable;

        return true;
    }
    else return false; 
}


int main()
{   
    int** piTable;

    b_alloc_table_2_dim(piTable, 5, 3);

    b_dealloc_table_2_dim(piTable, 5);
}
```

Comment: I failed to spot what was wrong in OP's code, maybe you can point out what OP did wrong and how you corrected it?

Comment: I got a problem now in main when i call b_alloc_table_2_dim: use of uninitialized memory. of piTable

Comment: @Magdalena Yes, because your code is correct as far as we can see and this answer is flat out wrong. `b_alloc_table_2_dim` will only modify the local variable `piTable`. The `piTable` from `main` remains unchanged and thus uninitialized.